# How do I use >>= to chain basic Int operations?

Tags: haskell, monads

Let's consider:

```
f :: Int
f = return 64 >>= (\x -> x^2) >>= (\y -> y^2)
```

GHCi rejects my code with

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `m0 b0'
    In the expression: return 64 >>= (\ x -> x ^ 2) >>= (\ y -> y ^ 2)
    In an equation for `f':
        f = return 64 >>= (\ x -> x ^ 2) >>= (\ y -> y ^ 2)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The result should be or at least related to 281,474,976,710,656 (64 squared followed by raising the result to the fourth power).
I cannot solve this problem. And it is connected with my misunderstanding of monads. Please help.

Comment: Why would you? Plain int operations aren't monadic. (Unless you count the identity monad.)

Comment: Note that `(\x -> x^2) >>= (\y _ -> y^4) $ 64` compiles and is `281474976710656` What's the monad?

Comment: @Michael The monad is `((->) Int)`: functions that take an `Int` as argument and return some type `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to look at (>>=). It has type

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

In english: the second argument of (>>=) must be function that produces a monadic value. Your functions just produce numbers.

The confusion comes about because you state that `f` will be an `Int`. Yet the compiler knows that (>>=) will return a `m b`
Thus the error message: because of your annotation it expected to find `Int`, but all it got was `m0 b0`

Note that your code for `f` could be correct for a type that is both a number with a sensible implementation of (^) and a monad. But `Int` is not such a type.

What you want is probably:

```
f = return 64 >>= pure . (^2) >>= pure . (^4)
```

or

```
f = (\x -> (x^2)^4) <$> return 64
```

But this will still not be a plain `Int` but an `Int` in some monad! Thus:

```
f :: Monad m => m Int
```

(I think you'll have to turn off the monomorphism restriction to make this actually compile.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does mean `<$>`

Comment: @Gilgamesz it is the infix operator that does the same as `fmap`